# Can I downgrade SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard To Web Edition?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

We are running a SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard Evaluation version. The client has decided they don't want to pay for full SQL Server standard and feel the Web edition is suitable. Can I downgrade SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard Evaluation to Web Edition?

Obviously I need to put a licence on it. Can I just put the Web edition licence on it and it will become a Web Edition server or does it require a re-install.

Comment: What did Microsoft say when you asked them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](http://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)

Comment: I don't deal with that part of the business etc. (and it would take me an age to get a response) I just needed to know from a technical point and just hoped someone may have actually done it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should answer your question:

MSDN: [Downgrading from SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Edition (trial) to R2 Web Edition (licensed)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlsetupandupgrade/thread/a6a16420-8dd1-4e7f-8003-11c8ed8b44a5)

You only need to uninstall Analysis service before running edition upgrade. And, of course, make a just-in-case database backup.